# I'm using Redis for inventory management and I'm having trouble with inventory calculation results for concurrent requests

Tags: spring-boot, redis

While using Redis for inventory management, I discovered an issue where inventory calculation results returned unexpected results. I originally solved the problem by using an inventory RDB and JPA's Lock to handle concurrency.
To increase TPS, we changed the inventory DB to Redis, and as a result of making 1000 simultaneous requests, the number decreased by about 1200 (a different value is returned each time higher than 1000).

I changed Redis because I thought it wouldn't cause concurrency problems, but why does this happen?

There are two types of products

PRODUCT:5
{
"productId" : 5,
"remain" : 10000
}

PRODUCT:7
{
"productId" : 7,
"remain" : 10000
}

Use jmeter simultaneously
Created 1000 inventory reduction APIs.

The execution flow of the API is as follows and Redis inventory classes are:
Why does this problem occur?
Here is a link to the code.
[please click here](https://github.com/Junobee25/ecommerce-backend/issues/20)

The expected result is:

PRODUCT:5
{
"productId" : 5,
"remain" : 9500
}

PRODUCT:7
{
"productId" : 7,
"remain" : 9500
}

But result is :

PRODUCT:5
{
"productId" : 5,
"remain" : 9278
}

PRODUCT:7
{
"productId" : 7,
"remain" : 9360
}